# The archive after upload be damaged PHP

Tags: php, ftp, zip

Well, to start, my English isn't very good. Apologies.

My problem is that I have this code, but when I upload, the archive goes, but stays damaged.

Source:

```
<?php
$servidor = 'mysite';
$usuario = 'user';
$senha = 'pass'; 

$ftp = ftp_connect($servidor);

$login = ftp_login($ftp, $usuario, $senha);


$local_arquivo = './arquivos/documento.doc';
$ftp_pasta = '/public_html/arquivos/';
$ftp_arquivo = 'documento.doc';

// Envia o arquivo pelo FTP em modo ASCII
$envio = ftp_put($ftp, $ftp_pasta.$ftp_arquivo, $local_arquivo, FTP_ASCII);
```

Thanks ;)

Comment: __Binary__ file formats like `.doc` files need to be uploaded in FTP_BINARY mode, not FTP_ASCII

Comment: I try with FTP_Binary and problem persists.

Comment: What is the value of `$envoi` after the upload?

Comment: The value is true, he send the archive but damaged, im going do a video to show better my problem.

Comment: Video with my problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1_SvIfxOR0

Comment: Did you compare the size of the uploaded file with the original? Perhaps the max execution time setting is kicking in - try adding `set_time_limit(0);` to the beginning of your script.

Comment: I put set_time_limit(0); and the error persists, the size of the archive in cpanel is 0 bytes.

Comment: Finnaly i can resolve the problem ;) Please close this question.